# Getting "blocked by CORS policy" error for only PUT request from angular 7

Tags: angular, spring-mvc, cors

I am creating a CRUD application using spring MVC and angular 7.
I have allowed CORS in my spring application, but when I call the PUT request from angular, I get a "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/BookAPI/api/updateBook/70' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error

I have enabled the CORS in my spring-mvc application

package com.book.spring.controller;

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.book.spring.models.Book;
import com.book.spring.service.BookService;
@CrossOrigin("*")
@RequestMapping("/api")
@RestController
public class BookController {
    @Autowired
    private BookService bookService;

    // Save a book
    @PostMapping("/create")
    public ResponseEntity<String> createBook(@RequestBody Book book) {
        Long bookId = bookService.create(book);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body("Book created with ID =" + bookId);
    }

    // Get All books
    @GetMapping("/getBooks")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Book>> listbooks() {
        List<Book> list = bookService.getAllBooks();
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(list);
    }

    // Get a book by its ID
    @GetMapping("/getBookByID/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Book> getBookById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        Book book = bookService.getBookById(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(book);
    }

    // Update a book
    @PutMapping("/updateBook/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateBook(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody Book book) {
        bookService.updateBook(id, book);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body("Book updated");
    }

    // Delete a book
    @DeleteMapping("/deleteBook/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteBook(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        bookService.deleteBook(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body("Book has be deleted");
    }
}


bookservice.ts:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as UrlConstants from './urls';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { Book } from './book/book';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
});  
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BookService {
  private _getBooksUrl: string = UrlConstants.BOOKS_URL;
  private _postBooksUrl: string = UrlConstants.POST_BOOK_URL;
  private _deleteBooksUrl: string = UrlConstants.DELETE_BOOK_URL;
  private _getBookUrl: string = UrlConstants.GET_BOOK_URL;
  private _putBookUrl: string = UrlConstants.PUT_BOOK_URL;
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }
  getAllBooks(): Observable<Book[]> {
    console.log(this._getBooksUrl);
    return this._http.get<Book[]>(this._getBooksUrl)
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
  }

  addBook(book: Book) {
    console.log("adding book");
    if (book.id) {
      return this._http.post(this._putBookUrl + book.id, {"title":book.title,"author":book.author}, { responseType: 'text',headers:headers})
        .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandlerPost));
    } else {
      return this._http.post(this._postBooksUrl, book, { responseType: 'text' })
        .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandlerPost));
    }
  }

  deleteBook(id: string) {
    return this._http.delete(this._deleteBooksUrl + id, { responseType: 'text' })
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandlerPost));
  }


  getBookById(bookId: string): Observable<Book> {
    return this._http.get<Book>(this._getBookUrl + bookId)
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandlerPost));
  }
  errorHandler(errorHandler: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<Book[]> {
    return throwError(errorHandler.message || "server error");
  }
  errorHandlerPost(errorHandler: HttpErrorResponse) {
    return throwError(errorHandler.message || "server error");
  }
}


consts:
export const BOOKS_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/BookAPI/api/getBooks';
export const POST_BOOK_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/BookAPI/api/create';
export const DELETE_BOOK_URL ='http://localhost:8080/BookAPI/api/deleteBook/';
export const GET_BOOK_URL ='http://localhost:8080/BookAPI/api/getBookByID/';
export const PUT_BOOK_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/BookAPI/api/updateBook/';
```

it should allow for all requests

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' header in the API response to allow PUT requests.

Answer (score 1):

After two days of too many searching. I finally found the answer!!

It was a problem with IIS Itself with the
WebDAVModule which seems to block PUT and DELETE methods by default!

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

I really hope no one else pain with that! =]

Fonte: https://mozartec.com/asp-net-core-error-405-methods-not-allowed-for-put-and-delete-requests-when-hosted-on-iis/

Answer (score 0):

you should use this._http.put for put request , you are not suppose to use post client for put request.

**change from**

return **this._http.post**(this._putBookUrl + book.id, {"title":book.title,"author":book.author}, { responseType: 'text',headers:headers})
        .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandlerPost));

**to** 
 return **this._http.put**(this._putBookUrl + book.id, {"title":book.title,"author":book.author}, { responseType: 'text',headers:headers})
        .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandlerPost));